# Remove ng-repeat duplicates

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have already read about this but didn't understand how to do this kind of things.

```
<div class='dropdown2'>
     <span>Seleziona Campionato:      </span>
     <select class='opzioni' ng-model="campionatoSelected">
              <option ng-repeat="team in teams  | filter: {Paese:nazioniSelected} track by $index" value="{{team.Campionato}}">{{team.Campionato}}
             </option>
     </select>
</div>
```

This is the piece of code that gives me duplicates, cause in every league (campionato) there are many teams. How can i cut the duplicates off this select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `unique` filter provided by the module `angular-filter` (https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) and cut off all the duplicates using the property you want to use for filtering:

```
<select class='opzioni' ng-model="campionatoSelected">
  <option ng-repeat="team in teams | filter: {Paese:nazioniSelected} | unique: 'MY_PROPERTY_NAME' track by $index" value="{{team.Campionato}}">{{team.Campionato}}
  </option>
</select>
```

You can also define your private filter and use that for doing both the operations you want to without adding third party modules.

PS: I am Italian like you, so I got your point, but try to use English variable/function names, it would make the code so much more readable, especially if then you want to post it somewhere or share it in general.

Comment: ok i will improve this part of my code. But this unique is not working for me. the teams array has a field that is called Campionato. So when i do this:<option ng-repeat="team in teams  | filter: {Paese:nazioniSelected} | unique: 'Campionato' track by $index" value="{{team.Campionato}}">{{team.Campionato}}                        it shows me nothing inside the select

Comment: sorry my bad, the `unique` filter is not available by default, you should add the following module with a lot of useful filters, or as I changed in the answer, define your own without adding third party dependencies: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter